# how is the theme unit test data licensed?

Tags: licensing

Can I use the theme uint test data in a demonstration site for a commercial theme? Or am I only allowed to use it for internal development?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything on the Codex is GPL (or can be considered as GPL-compatible). Insofar as any part of the Theme Unit Test data are copyrightable, unless stated otherwise you may assume that the WordPress Foundation holds the copyright, and that the work is released under the GPL.

Feel free to use it however you see fit!

Comment: What about images? There is no indication where they actually come from. I had doubts about Peter Pan excerpt, but after some quick googling it seems to be public domain.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the images are all from burningwell.org, and are Public Domain. I used the Peter Pan excerpt precisely because it's in the public domain. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's allowed as you see it more often (or no one is judging it). It'd also be only 1h of work to make your own. Else, I'd say: Ask @Chip Bennet.

Comment: I tweeted Chip, asking to take a look at this question.

Comment: True, I could quickly make my own.. the reason I wanted to use the TUT data is that it provides a reference point, it's easier to compare themes if they demo the same content, and the TUT data has been carefully designed to fit the core WP elements.

Comment: Without talking bullshit about Chips Work: There is still place for evolution. Even if you copy it 1:1.01, it'll be your own work.

Comment: Most of it isn't my original work, anyway. The Theme Unit Test data set predates my involvement with Theme Review. I've only updated/maintained it for the past year or so. Personally, I question how much of it is copyrightable, anyway, outside of the specific compilation itself. Thus, my intentionally carefully-worded answer.